# Abbreviate text labels in ggalluvial plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a [ggalluvial plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZaQw.png). 
The code I have used to obtain the plot is:

```
ggplot(sample.data,
       aes(y = N, axis1 = N, axis2 = V1, axis3 = V2, axis4 = V5)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = N, color = N), 
                width = 1/12, alpha = 0.7, 
                knot.pos = 0.4,  reverse = TRUE, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_stratum( aes(fill = N), width = 1/8, color = "black",  show.legend = FALSE)+
  geom_label(stat = "stratum", label.strata = TRUE) +
  geom_text( stat = "stratum", label.strata = TRUE, show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:4, labels = c("N", "V1", "V2", "V5"))+
  ggtitle("Test2") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
        legend.position = "top"
        )
```

As seen from the plot, the lables are big and unreadable. How can I abbreviate them and add a legend to the plot? I would prefer a function to do this so I can remove the first axis(N) labels altogether.

Also, how to add gaps between the stratum?

Comment: `Error in ggplot(sample.data, aes(y = N, axis1 = N, axis2 = V1, axis3 = V2,  : 
  object 'sample.data' not found`

Answer (score 0):

*How can I abbreviate the labels?*

You can either

- process your dataframe column containing labels and do some string manipulation on it. For example so it would extract first *n* characters or words from the label and use them.  But I am not sure if you can get a desired outcome that way.

OR

- You replace your column(s) with non-abbreviated labels with a new column(s) with abbreviated labels. E.g. provide the abbreviated labels directly.

*How can I  add a legend to the plot?*

You can probably add the legend by setting `show.legend=TRUE`

*How to add gaps between the stratum?*

If you want to spread the strata vertically, you could try give the `geom_stratum` `x`, `y`, `ymin` and `ymax` arguments (though it can be complicated). Easier way would be to set borders to your strata so it would look like there are gaps. That you can do by giving the `geom_stratum` corresponding arguments for borders - `size` and `color`.